# Sitecore EXM View Online link issue

Tags: exm

We are using Email Experience Manager 3.4.0 rev. 161028. In our newsletter, we included a link (anchor tag) to view the online version of the email.

The links works well in local and staging but it is failing on production. The production url throws the "`This site can’t be reached`" error.

The crypto keys are fine. `Analytics.Clustername` points to hostname and other settings are OK as per configuration guide.

Not sure as to what's going wrong here..any clue?

Url format below

```
https://<oursitename>>/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_eq=d5FVcEM0YRbUNUUoMLex%2ft9aC6PyZbfOZtKTGZAFP%2bLfU5wcRZQXEOpv2UZrRu%2bFR42W11UpbXG%2bMrZyqRdGlys4ooVq2UfU9q8OfDXzYiHCcTCRn4xblXsR0S8YS0eu%2fBycWbEivNmNQX2VauYUjb43TLQab4a75YMYWMJrH7qTH7dbcmAi5zeeVfokCKv1B8F5G7N1P6bZBeygKhf6klz6%2fiqnuYKWrCU16TgWYcFQK9YVnRJG5gEdyh9vNy%2bQFRb15NeJUAXV7EcMyM7Q5%2bReQJPTeAaw%2bAcABu7cJLeJC4bBn1sEyKxoVsg6PxSDe4Bqj%2fvne6ptDdjCCqiH4g%3d%3d
```

EXM Root settings
[image]

Comment: You urls starts with `https://>/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx`. Notice the `>` character. For me it looks like you have a config issue on prod with too many closing tag characters `>`.

Comment: @VijayaAkkenapally Is the link above the link coming out of the Email (malformed with a missing base address)? If so, make sure that Base Url is set in the Email Manager Root

Comment: @PeteNavarra Actually, the base url is set in the email manager root. Here is the actual url..I wanted to hide the client name :) so remove it from the link.https://www.vichealth.vic.gov.au/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_eq=d5FVcEM0YRbUNUUoMLex%2ft9aC6PyZbfOZtKTGZAFP%2bLfU5wcRZQXEOpv2UZrRu%2bFR42W11UpbXG%2bMrZyqRdGlys4ooVq2UfU9q8OfDXzYiHCcTCRn4xblXsR0S8YS0eu%2fBycWbEivNmNQX2VauYUjb43TLQab4a75YMYWMJrH7qTH7dbcmAi5zeeVfokCKv1B8F5G7N1P6bZBeygKhf6klz6%2fiqnuYKWrCU16TgWYcFQK9YVnRJG5gEdyh9vNy%2bQFRb15NeJUAXV7EcMyM7Q5%2bReQJPTeAaw%2bAcABu7cJLeJC4bBn1sEyKxoVsg6PxSDe4Bqj%2fvne6ptDdjCCqiH4g%3d%3d

Comment: Was this a new EXM install or upgrade?  Also, does RedirectUrlPage.aspx exist under /sitecore on the CD?

Comment: @PeteNavarra This is a new EXM install. The RedirectUrlPage.aspx  page exists on the CD server. One thing I need clarification is on the "targethostname" attribute defined on the sitedefinition element. Can you suggest if targethostname attribute has any role in the exm dispatch or redirect? How should it look like for the above url?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your Email Manager Root settings?

Comment: @PeteNavarra I've added the screen shot of settngs in the question itself. Please check